# Remove punctuation but keeping emoticons?

Tags: string, r, text, gsub, emoticons

Is that possible to remove all the punctuations but keeping the emoticons such as

:-(

:)

:D

:p

```
structure(list(text = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label =     c("ãããæããããéãããæãããInappropriate announce:-(", 
"@AirAsia your direct debit (Maybank) payment gateways is not working. Is it something     you are working to fix?", 
"@AirAsia Apart from the slight delay and shortage of food on our way back from Phuket, both flights were very smooth. Kudos :)", 
"RT @AirAsia: ØØÙØÙÙÙÙ ÙØØØ ØØØÙ ÙØØØØÙ ØØØØÙÙÙí í Now you can enjoy a #great :D breakfast onboard with our new breakfast meals! :D", 
"xdek ke flight @AirAsia Malaysia to LA... hahah..:p bagi la promo murah2 sikit, kompom aku beli...", 
"You know there is a problem when customer service asks you to wait for 103 minutes and your no is 42 in the queue. X-("
), class = "factor"), created = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("1/2/2014 16:14", "1/2/2014 17:00", "3/2/2014 0:54", 
"3/2/2014 0:58", "3/2/2014 1:28"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("text", 
"created"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: tokenize the emoticons first (`gsub` them with a token like $SMILEY1), then do the punctuation removal then replace the emotitokens with the emoticons

Comment: How if for some emoticons such as =( I will get an error message "Error in gsub("=(", "emoticons", Data_edited_txt$text) : 
  invalid regular expression '=(', reason 'Missing ')''"

Comment: @user3456230 you get the error because `(` should be escaped in a regex, see the `escape_regex` function in my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23447977/3309529).

Comment: (+1), nice challenge. But why on earth would you want to keep emoticons? :)

Comment: Hi @RichardScriven This is for sentiment analysis on tweets. Some emoticons bring a positive sentiment and some negative :-)

Comment: @Richard, they are hugely important.  They represent a person's attempt to re-inject embodied displays of emotion, gesture, and body language back into the virtual space.  They carry a great deal of information.  PS if anyone here runs an online class an discourages emoticons as unscholarly I'd challenge you to stop as you're tremendously constraining the dialogue to assure you get no real discourse.  It'd be like having students in classes not be able to use facial expressions, glances, move their body or gesture.

Comment: @TylerRinker, I meant no disrespect.  The topic is highly opinionated and dependent on generation I suppose.

Comment: @RichardScriven Sorry no disrespect taken, this illustrates the point that written language is hard to get people's tone.  You misread my impassioned excitement as offense :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach that is less sophisticated and likely slower than @gagolews's solution.  It requires you feed it an emoticon dictionary.  You can create that or use the one in the `qdapDictionaries` package.  The basic approach converts the emoticons to text that couldn't be mistaken for anything else (I use `dat$Temp <-` prefix to ensure this).  Then you strip out punctuation using `qdap::strip` and then convert the placeholders back into emoticons via `mgsub`:

```
library(qdap)
#reps <- emoticon
emos <- c(":-(", ":)", ":D", ":p", "X-(")
reps <- data.frame(seq_along(emos), emos)

reps[, 1] <- paste0("EMOTICONREPLACE", reps[, 1])
dat$Temp <- mgsub(as.character(reps[, 2]), reps[, 1], dat[, 1])
dat$Temp <- mgsub(reps[, 1], as.character(reps[, 2]), 
    strip(dat$Temp, digit.remove = FALSE, lower.case=FALSE))
```

View it:

```
truncdf(left_just(dat[, 3, drop=F]), 50)

##   Temp                                              
## 1 RT AirAsia ØØÙØÙÙÙÙ ÙØØØ ØØØÙ ÙØØØØÙ ØØØØÙÙÙí í No
## 2 You know there is a problem when customer service 
## 3 ãããæããããéãããæãããInappropriate announce:-(         
## 4 AirAsia your direct debit Maybank payment gateways
## 5 xdek ke flight AirAsia Malaysia to LA hahah:p bagi
## 6 AirAsia Apart from the slight delay and shortage o
```

**EDIT**: To keep the `?` and `!` as requested pass the `char.keep` argument in `strip` function:

```
dat$Temp <- mgsub(reps[, 1], as.character(reps[, 2]), 
    strip(dat$Temp, digit.remove = FALSE, lower.case=FALSE, char.keep=c("!", "?")))
```

Comment: Quite a nice solution, but what about `:-(` in the 3rd string...?

Comment: I think he wants to keep it.  That's why its there.

Comment: @TylerRinker,thanks for the great solution! In this case, is that possible to keep Exclamation(!) and question mark (?) as well? I need that for sentiment analysis

Comment: That's a really great and creative solution.

Comment: Hi @TylerRinker, is that possible to convert all the wordings to lower case and removing the numerics BUT keeping the capital letter and numerid for the emoticons such as :D and :8?

Comment: I think setting `lower.case = TRUE` will work inside of the last code chunk's `strip`.

Comment: If I put lower.case=TRUE, I will get something like this:  "now you can enjoy a great emoticonreplace52 breakfast onboard with our new breakfast meals! emoticonreplace52".. The same if I put 'digit.remove=TRUE'

Comment: Think through how to solve this.  The `tolower` function would work here when you supply the dictionary to convert back.

Comment: @TylerRinker, I tried my best to figure it out but I failed =(

Comment: @TylerRinker I know this is an old post, but I was wondering if you could help. I have the same problem, where I need to keep the emoticons. I was going through your example, but I get the error message "object dat not found". What's dat?

Comment: The original data set from the OP

Answer (score 7):

## 1. A working pure-regex solution (a.k.a. Edit#2)

This task **can** be done *purely* with regular expressions (many thanks to @Mike Samuel)

First we build a database of emoticons:

```
(emots <- as.character(outer(c(":", ";", ":-", ";-"),
+                c(")", "(", "]", "[", "D", "o", "O", "P", "p"), stri_paste)))
## [1] ":)"  ";)"  ":-)" ";-)" ":("  ";("  ":-(" ";-(" ":]"  ";]"  ":-]" ";-]" ":["  ";["  ":-[" ";-[" ":D"  ";D"  ":-D" ";-D"
## [21] ":o"  ";o"  ":-o" ";-o" ":O"  ";O"  ":-O" ";-O" ":P"  ";P"  ":-P" ";-P" ":p"  ";p"  ":-p" ";-p"
```

An exemplary input text:

```
text <- ":) ;P :] :) ;D :( LOL :) I've been to... the (grocery) st{o}re :P :-) --- and the salesperson said: Oh boy!"
```

A helper function that escapes some special characters so that they may be used in a regex pattern (using the [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package):

```
library(stringi)
escape_regex <- function(r) {
   stri_replace_all_regex(r, "\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]", "\\\\$0")
}
```

A regular expression to match the emoticons:

```
(regex1 <- stri_c("(", stri_c(escape_regex(emots), collapse="|"), ")"))
## [1] "(:\\)|;\\)|:-\\)|;-\\)|:\\(|;\\(|:-\\(|;-\\(|:\\]|;\\]|:-\\]|;-\\]|:\\[|;\\[|:-\\[|;-\\[|:D|;D|:-D|;-D|:o|;o|:-o|;-o|:O|;O|:-O|;-O|:P|;P|:-P|;-P|:p|;p|:-p|;-p)"
```

Now, as @Mike Samuel suggested below, we just match `(emoticon)|punctuation`
(note that emoticons are in a capturing group) and then replace the matches
with the result of capturing group 1 (so if it's an emoticon, we have replacement=*this emoticon*, if it's a punctuation char, we have replacement=*nothing*). This will work because the alternation with `|` in ICU Regex (which is the regex engine used in `stri_replace_all_regex`) is [greedy and left-biased](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): emoticons will be matched earlier than the punctuation characters.

```
stri_replace_all_regex(text, stri_c(regex1, "|\\p{P}"), "$1")
## [1] ":) ;P :] :) ;D :( LOL :) Ive been to the grocery store :P :-)  and the salesperson said Oh boy"
```

BTW, if you want to get rid only of a selected set of characters, put e.g. `[.,]` instead of `[\\p{P}]` above.

## 2. Regex solution hint - my first (not wise) attempt (a.k.a. original answer)

My very first idea (left here mainly for "historical reasons") was to approach this problem by using [look-aheads and look-behinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but - as you see - that's far from perfect.

To remove all `:` and `;` not followed by `)`, `(`, `D`, `X`, `8`, `[`, or `]` use negative look-behind:

```
stri_replace_all_regex(text, "[:;](?![)P(DX8\\[\\]])", "")
## [1] ":) :8 ;P :] :) ;D :( LOL :) I've been to... the grocery store :P -) --- and the salesperson said Oh boy!"
```

Now we can add some old-school emoticons (with noses, e.g. `:-)`, `;-D` etc.)

```
stri_replace_all_regex(text, "[:;](?![-]?[)P(DX8\\[\\]])", "")
## [1] ":) :8 ;P :] :) ;D :( LOL :) I've been to... the grocery store :P :-) --- and the salesperson said Oh boy!"
```

Now the hyphens removal (negative look behind and look ahead)

```
stri_replace_all_regex(text, "[:;](?![-]?[)P(DX8\\[\\]])|(?!<[:;])[-](?![)P(DX8\\[\\]])", "")
## [1] ":) :8 ;P :] :) ;D :( LOL :) I've been to... the grocery store :P :-)  and the salesperson said Oh boy!"
```

and so on. Of course, first you should build your own database of emoticons (to leave as they are) and punctuation marks (to remove). The regex will highly depend on these two sets, so it will be difficult to add new emoticons --- it's definitely not worth applying (and may twist your brain).

## 3. The second attempt (regex-dumb friendlier, a.k.a. Edit#1)

On the other hand, if you're allergic to complex regexes, try this. This approach has some "didactic benefits" - we have full insight on what's being done in each of the following steps:

1. Locate all emoticons within `text`;
2. Locate all the punctuation characters within `text`;
3. Find positions of the punctuation characters that are not parts of emoticons;
4. Remove the characters located in step 3.

An exemplary input text - 1 string only - a generalized case is left as an exercise ;)

```
text <- ":) ;P :] :) ;D :( LOL :) I've been to... the (grocery) st{o}re :P :-) --- and the salesperson said: Oh boy!"
```

A helper function that escapes some special characters so that they may be used in a regex:

```
escape_regex <- function(r) {
   library("stringi")
   stri_replace_all_regex(r, "\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]", "\\\\$0")
}
```

A regular expression to match the emoticons:

```
(regex1 <- stri_c("(", stri_c(escape_regex(emots), collapse="|"), ")"))
## [1] "(:\\)|;\\)|:-\\)|;-\\)|:\\(|;\\(|:-\\(|;-\\(|:\\]|;\\]|:-\\]|;-\\]|:\\[|;\\[|:-\\[|;-\\[|:D|;D|:-D|;-D|:o|;o|:-o|;-o|:O|;O|:-O|;-O|:P|;P|:-P|;-P|:p|;p|:-p|;-p)"
```

Locate the start and end positions of all the emoticons (i.e. locate the first *OR* the second *OR* ... emoticon):

```
where_emots <- stri_locate_all_regex(text, regex1)[[1]] # only for the first string of text
print(where_emots)
##       start end
##  [1,]     1   2
##  [2,]     4   5
##  [3,]     7   8
##  [4,]    10  11
##  [5,]    13  14
##  [6,]    16  17
##  [7,]    23  24
##  [8,]    64  65
##  [9,]    67  69
```

Locate all the punctuation chars (Here `\\p{P}` is the [Unicode character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) representing punctuation characters):

```
where_punct <- stri_locate_all_regex(text, "\\p{P}")[[1]]
print(where_punct)
##       start end
##  [1,]     1   1
##  [2,]     2   2
##  [3,]     4   4
##  [4,]     7   7
##  [5,]     8   8
## ...
## [26,]    72  72
## [27,]    73  73
## [28,]    99  99
## [29,]   107 107
```

As some punctuation chars occur within the emoticons, we should not stage them for removal:

```
which_punct_omit <- sapply(1:nrow(where_punct), function(i) {
   any(where_punct[i,1] >= where_emots[,1] &
        where_punct[i,2] <= where_emots[,2]) })
where_punct <- where_punct[!which_punct_omit,] # update where_punct
print(where_punct)
##       start end
##  [1,]    27  27
##  [2,]    38  38
##  [3,]    39  39
##  [4,]    40  40
##  [5,]    46  46
##  [6,]    54  54
##  [7,]    58  58
##  [8,]    60  60
##  [9,]    71  71
## [10,]    72  72
## [11,]    73  73
## [12,]    99  99
## [13,]   107 107
```

Each punctuation mark surely consists only of 1 character, thus always `where_punct[,1]==where_punct[,2]`.

Now the final part. As you see, `where_punct[,1]` contains the positions of characters to be removed. IMHO the easiest way to do that (without loops) is by converting a string to UTF-32 (each character == 1 integer), remove undesired elements, and then go back to the textual representation:

```
text_tmp <- stri_enc_toutf32(text)[[1]]
print(text_tmp) # here - just ASCII codes...
## [1]  58  41  32  59  80  32  58  93  32  58....
text_tmp <- text_tmp[-where_punct[,1]] # removal, but be sure that where_punct is not empty!
```

And the result is:

```
stri_enc_fromutf32(text_tmp)
## [1] ":) ;P :] :) ;D :( LOL :) Ive been to the grocery store :P :-)  and the salesperson said Oh boy"
```

Here you are.

Comment: Why not just match `(emoticon)|punctuation` (note that emoticons are in a capturing group) and then replace with the result of capturing group 1 which matches just the emoticons?  Since `|` is greedy and left-biased, emoticons will match early and often.

Comment: Perfect! Can you post an answer with this idea? I have some R code that uses this regex feature and works as expected. I don't want to get credit for that :)

Comment: I know very little R, so I don't think I'd add anything by actually writing code and this answer already contributes a lot by defining `emots` in a maintainable way.  I think a simple `sub(paste("(", emots, ")", punctuation), "\\1", ...)` should do it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for noting the vertical bar's behavior. I was completely unaware of that.

Comment: Yep.  In most regex libraries, searching for `a|ab` in `"abcd"` will match just the `"a"` because backtracking tree interpreter will early out on the first successful interpretation to avoid factorial time badness on inputs that match the greedy path.  That the `|` in PCRE regex is much closer to the `/` operator in analytic grammars can cause subtle bugs, but there's no way to deprecate `|` in favor of `/` because `/` is used to delimit regular expression literals in many glue languages.

Comment: And this lack of commutativity of `|` does also occur in ICU regexes (used by `stri_replace_all_regex` above). And what's interesting (at least to me), the default regex engine in R, ERE TRE (PCRE is only used on user's explicit demand), always tries to retrieve the longest match.

Comment: Yeah.  Automaton-based libraries that are guaranteed O(n) don't suffer a penalty but they might suffer if they try to make hard guarantees about where capturing groups are when the match is ambiguous: `(a*)(a*)` can match ('a' x n) n-ways so an efficient automaton library might just advertise sub-expressions as repeatable undefined-behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I added this functionality to `qdap version > 2.0.0` as the `sub_holder` function. Basically this function uses [the response I gave above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23448576/1000343) but lightens the coding load.  The `sub_holder` function takes a text vector and items you want to sub out (such as emoticons).  It returns a list with:

1. the vector of the test with the items subbed out for place holders
2. A function (called `unhold`) that swaps the holders for the original terms

Here's the code:

```
emos <- c(":-(", ":)", ":D", ":p", "X-(")
(m <- sub_holder(emos, dat[,1]))
m$unhold(strip(m$output, digit.remove = FALSE, lower.case=FALSE, char.keep=c("!", "?")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.  It will automatically escape characters as necessary, and will or all the elements of a vector if put into the `or()` function.  `re_matches()` with the global argument will get you a list of all of the emoticons for a given line.

```
x = structure(list(text = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label =     c("ãããæããããéãããæãããInappropriate announce:-(", 
"@AirAsia your direct debit (Maybank) payment gateways is not working. Is it something     you are working to fix?", 
"@AirAsia Apart from the slight delay and shortage of food on our way back from Phuket, both flights were very smooth. Kudos :)", 
"RT @AirAsia: ØØÙØÙÙÙÙ ÙØØØ ØØØÙ ÙØØØØÙ ØØØØÙÙÙí í Now you can enjoy a #great :D breakfast onboard with our new breakfast meals! :D", 
"xdek ke flight @AirAsia Malaysia to LA... hahah..:p bagi la promo murah2 sikit, kompom aku beli...", 
"You know there is a problem when customer service asks you to wait for 103 minutes and your no is 42 in the queue. X-("
), class = "factor"), created = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("1/2/2014 16:14", "1/2/2014 17:00", "3/2/2014 0:54", 
"3/2/2014 0:58", "3/2/2014 1:28"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("text", 
"created"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

emots <- as.character(outer(c(":", ";", ":-", ";-"), c(")", "(", "]", "[", "D", "o", "O", "P", "p"), paste0))

library(rex)
re_matches(x$text,
  rex(
    capture(name = 'emoticons',
      or(emots)
    ),
  global = T)

#>[[1]]
#>  emoticon
#>1       :D
#>2       :D
#>
#>[[2]]
#>  emoticon
#>1     <NA>
#>
#>[[3]]
#>  emoticon
#>1      :-(
#>
#>[[4]]
#>  emoticon
#>1     <NA>
#>
#>[[5]]
#>  emoticon
#>1       :p
#>
#>[[6]]
#>  emoticon
#>1       :)
```